# Interpretation of coefficients when multiplied OLS

Tags: least-squares, regression-coefficients

Suppose I have a Ordinary Least Squares model of this form:

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_1*X_2$

**What would be an interpretation for the coefficient $\beta_3$?**
(Suppose that $X_1$ & $X_2$ are not binary)

For example:

$Y$ = price of house
$X_1$ = squared meters of the property
$X_2$ = number of bathrooms

Comment: Please search this site for [interaction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interaction+interpret*).